# If the set of linear transformation is a vector space, can we change the underlying field?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, the set of linear transformations is a vector space. But I am curious about the underlying field for this vector space. The field for $V$ or $W$ is usually the real or complex number, but when it comes to the set of linear transformations, we only define the field to be the reals, but why can't it be other fields such as the complex number or some other field?

Comment: No, we don't only define the field to be the reals.  We have $\operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)$.

Comment: Given vector spaces $V$ and $W$ *over the same field*, say $F$, then the set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W$ is also a vector space over $F$, where: if $T : V \to W$ is linear, and $a \in F$, we define the linear transformation $aT : V \to W$ by $(aT)(v) = aT(v)$ for all $v \in V$.

Answer (score 0):

The algebraic way is to use tensor products, called extension of scalars.

If $K$ is a field, $V$ a $K$-vector space, and $L$ a field extension of $K$ (a field containing $K$), then $V\otimes_K L$ is an $L$-vector space.

Comment: ok I guess I'll learn about those eventually. For now, we are only using the reals